# Cakephp Multilanguage setup without default i18n setup

Tags: cakephp, routes, multilingual

I need to implement a multilingual website using Cakephp. I just want to implement this based on url like http://domain.com/fre/login  or, http://domain.com/eng/login. I don't want to configure default localization and i18n db. Is it possible to implement there?, if possible then what is the necessary settings I have to do to go forward?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Routing prefixes.

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('fre', 'eng'));
```